# Powershell conditionals return non bool results

Tags: string, windows, powershell

I want the result to be a bool $true or $false

```
$testlist = @("red","orange","green")
$testlist -eq "green"
```

This should result in $True, but instead it results in "green"

to contrast

```
$testlist -ne "green"
```

Returns the other values as string except for "green"

Neat feature to find the values you are looking for, but useless for actual conditional returns as it results in $True every time as it is a non zero length value.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.The concept of a conditional operator returning an array is an oddity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test if a value is in the array:

```
$testlist -contains "green"
```

Comment: Hi thanks, for this. I am actually using objects instead of strings, as I was trying to illustrate a concept using simplified code. But i think i found a workaround, the results isn't actually a string as get-member would indicate, it is actually an array, and can be manipulated as such.

Comment: _You should test if a value is in the array_: That is what `-eq` is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the result to be a bool `$true` or `$false`

Well the code you are running can be evaluated as a boolean and you would still get the same results. Pretty much and nonzero integer and nonempty string will be cast as a boolean easy.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> $testlist = @("red","orange","green")
[bool]($testlist -eq "green")
True
```

`-eq`, and many other operators like `-match`, work with arrays and scalar values.

While it hides what is happening behind the scenes this would work as an `if` statement.

```
if($testlist -eq "green"){"Green is in there"}
```

Not sure if this occurred to you or not but how your code is being evaluated is that PowerShell is returning all array members that satisfy the query. Consider this as another example:

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> $testlist = @("red","orange","green","green")
$testlist -eq "green"
green
green
```

You see that it returned green twice since it was in the array twice.

[4c74356b41's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544484/3829407) uses the `-contains` array operator which by design returns a boolean. If you have at least v3 you can also use the more intuitive `-in` which works almost the same way.

```
"green" -in "red","orange","green"
```

I just wanted to be sure you knew what was going on and there is *usually* a method to PowerShell's madness

Comment: the cast to bool is pretty clever, I like it ;)